# Maximum DTC and maximum DTZ in the endgame KRPKRP

Tags: tablebases, rook-endgame

What is the maximum DTC and the maximum DTZ in the endgame KRPKRP (rook+pawn
 against rook+pawn) ?

Comment: Please also show some position.

Answer (score 3):

According to [longest checkmates in chess](http://kirill-kryukov.com/chess/longest-checkmates/#3+3), the longest DTM (depth-to-*mate*) for KRP vs KRP is **112 moves**, starting from this position with white to move:

```
[FEN "8/7P/1K5R/8/1r1k4/8/4p3/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

The analysis ignores the 50 move rule.

Additionally, according to the [Syzygy tablebases.](https://syzygy-tables.info/?fen=8/8/8/1P3p2/8/8/2R2r2/k1K5_b_-_-_0_1), the maximum KRP-KRP DTZ is 122 ply.

```
[Title "DTZ 122 Ply"]
[FEN "8/8/8/1P3p2/8/8/2R2r2/k1K5 b - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: I already knew this collection of positions with the longest distance to mate. But I am looking for positions with longest distance to conversion or distance to zero. This example quickly turns into a queen+rook against queen+rook - battle, also interesting, but not what I am actually looking for.

Comment: @Peter: In hindsight I think it would have been beneficial if you had included your own research into the question, i.e. that you knew about the DTM analysis. Given that you asked the question 2+ years ago, it would be great if you could post an answer/updated question with the research you have conducted since then.